# java Queue interface polymorphism

Tags: java, interface, queue, polymorphism

I was reading http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

When you declare a queue in Java

```
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

What happens behind the scene ? because I see queue is an interface with just method signatures, and LinkedList doesn't directly implement it, so how does it override those methods (`add()`, `peek()`, `poll()`, `offer()`, and `remove()` ) and do the polymorphism like that ? I mean you can only access some certain methods but not all of them from `LinkedList` for example `public void add(int index, E element)` is no longer available as it makes the apparent type to Queue. Also didn't we need to cast it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code of the JDK:

```
public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
```

So `LinkedList<E>` doesn't directly implement `Queue<E>`, but it does implement `Deque<E>`, which extends `Queue<E>`:

```
public interface Deque<E> extends Queue<E> {
```

Threfore, `LinkedList<E>` inherits the abstract methods of `Queue<E>`.

The overriding methods are defined directly in `LinkedList<E>` - as usual.

Answer (score 2):

> because I see queue is an interface with just method signatures, and LinkedList doesn't directly implement it

LinkedList does implement a Queue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: sorry i was reading it from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html, where it doesn't implement Queue

Comment: Ah! LinkedList is implementing Deque which already extends Queue.

Answer (score 0):

[`LinkedList` does implement `Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).  When an object is declared using an interface, the compiler treats it solely as an object of that type.  however, since you cannot instantiate an interface, you need to instantiate it as a class that implements that interface.  In this case, you will not be able to access some of `LinkedList`'s methods, (`push()`, `pop()`, for example), because the compiler identifies `queue` as a `Queue<Integer>`.  However, since it was instantiated as a `LinkedList<Integer>`, and can be casted easily to a `LinkedList`.

Comment: sorry i was reading it from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html, where it doesn't implement Queue

Comment: PS:  The assignment of LinkedList to the Queue interface is referred to as a "Widening Conversion".  And push + pop are available on the Queue interface.  It's List specific methods like get that are not, hence they are not available if you declare your variable as Queue instance, even though the underlying object might have those methods.

Comment: @Matt try doing `Queue<String> l = new LinkedList<String>(); l.push("hello");`.  it will not compile.  push and pop are not available to `Queue`.  They are methods implemented from the `Stack` interface (which `LinkedList` also implements).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html